# Can <amp-ad> support dynamic allocation?

Tags: amp-html

The  example markup has a defined width and height.
https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/extensions/amp-ad/amp-ad.md

How can different ad sizes be served from DFP's dynamic allocation?

Answer (score 0):

I think AMP supports DFP as you can see examples in [AMP Ads Test Cases](https://dfp-amp-testing-1185.appspot.com/). You can also read in [AMP Support for DFP](https://support.google.com/dfp_premium/answer/6352089?hl=en)

> For publishers who use DFP, you can implement Accelerated Mobile Pages
>   to load your mobile web pages more quickly, but it’s about more than
>   just speed and performance. AMP promotes enhanced distribution so
>   publishers can take advantage of the open web’s potential for their
>   content to appear everywhere quickly — across platforms and apps.

1. First, we recommend learning more about AMP as a whole:
   technical specifications.
2. Next, learn how to implement ads within Accelerated Mobile Pages and how to integrate those with DFP.

Comment: Thanks @noogui
I think I found what I needed here: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/ads/google/doubleclick.md#multi-size-ad